# Backslash in URL causes 404 error

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, wamp

I have a search form on the page and I use `GET` method to send data to the server, but when I type backslash and click search, I see a `404` error. It is for "`\`" in URL. How can I prevent it?

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/SelfArea/wpzf/public/\
```

Apache server configuration `htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Windows 7, WAMP Server.

Comment: Could you please show us your .htaccess?

Comment: I just check on my ZF application, and it works normally, i.e. I get error: Invalid controller specified (%5C). Maybe you changed something in your htaccess?

Comment: @Marcin I update my question and add htaccess

Comment: I agree with Marcin. If that's all that is in the .htaccess, the problem is not with the .htaccess, but probably with the PHP code.

Comment: It is working as it should - Your browser should convert backslashes to forward slashes as a backslash is always incorrect. You need a new browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to note:

Point 1. Your browser should convert backslash to frontslash. Many browsers have "updated stuff" example: you cannot run direct javascript from address bar anymore in Chrome. However, a good programmer will always imagine a user to be more dumb than monkey, so your question makes perfect sense!

Point 2. If you are accepting parameters then, you might want to strip slashes using:

[Stripslashes Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Point 3. This will not be an issue in Linux system because, windows and linux both have different filing structure. Trust me, it will be ok :)

EDIT:

PS: You might want to test it on linux machine by putting it on "free hosting services"! that is , if you do not have a server already.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 step to load the page when routing error occurred in laravel :-

1. Add index.php in url the `localhost/project_name/index.php/page_name`
2. Edit `apache2.conf`  from `etc/apache2` Do following :-

`<Directory /usr/share>`

```
`AllowOverride All`

`Require all granted`
```

`</Directory>`

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>`
```

It will work fine handle all routing error.